# Inject Controller and Mock AngularJS Services

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, angularjs

I've finally managed to complete a very simple end to end test, i.e.

In **scenarios.js:**

```
describe('My app', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser().navigateTo('/');
    });

    describe('On Load', function () {
        it('Textbox should be blank', function () {
            expect(input('textbox').val()).toBe('');
        });
    });
});
```

And my **runner.html** looks like this:

```
<head>
    <title>End2end Test Runner</title>
    <script src="/js/libs/angular-scenario.js" ng-autotest></script>
    <script src="/js/libs/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/test/e2e/scenarios.js"></script>
</head>
```

This boots up my site, navigates, and checks an input is blank. Ace.

**However** I would like to now add this test which expands on what I have so far:

```
describe('Click on Add', function () {
    it('will add new item if valid', function () {
        input('newItemName').enter('Test Item');
        element('#add').click();
        expect(input('newItemName').val()).toBe('');
        expect(repeater('#items li').count()).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

But before I run this test I want to Mock the storage service my app is dependant on.

Here is my **controller definition**:

```
myapp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$filter', 'storage',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, $filter, storage) { 
        . . . . 
    }
]);
```

And this is causing me problems (I think), because I want to do something like this:

```
describe('Controller Unit Tests', function(){
    var ctrl;

    beforeEach(function(){
        ctrl = new MyController();
    });

    it('should ....', function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

But can't because of the way I am declaring my Controller. And the reason I am declaring my controller that way is for minification purposes...

Does anyone have an advice on how this problem could be solved?!

Comment: Would be great to add your testatcular config file, in particular you probably have specified a `urlRoot` other than `'/'`, in order to support your `browser().navigateTo('/')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
function MyController($scope, $routeParams, $filter, storage) {}
MyCtrl1.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$filter', 'storage'];
```

Comment: I found this - http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05 - on the Angular Tutorial (which I never read!) which has the answer and reason why this is correct. "A note on minification"...